# jquery/javascript -how to loop through array and create variables in each iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm wondering for some time now why this fails:

```
if (longest.length >= 3) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < longest.length-1; i++) {
      var $last[i] = longest[i].splice(-1).toString();
      //if ( $( $last[i] ).closest(':jqmData(role="panel")') == "popover" ) { 
      //var gotoPage = $last[i];
    // }
      }
    }
```

`longest` is an array, which contains array elements.

I want to loop through the number of arrays in `longest` and create variables from each nested arrays' last element. The .splice(-1).toString() fails telling me `"missing ; before statement"`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
longest will look something like this:

`[[#menu, #menuSub1, #menuSub2], [#main, yield, yield], [#pop1, #pop1-1, #pop1-2]]`

It's within a function to track the browser-history in a mobile-app with different panels.

**EDIT2:**
Finished code (Thx Mic):

```
if (longest.length >= 3) {
   var $last = [];
   for ( var i = 0; i < longest.length; i++) {
      $last.push( longest[i][ longest[i].length - 1 ]);
      if ( $( $last[i] ).closest(':jqmData(role="panel")').jqmData('panel')  == "popover" ) { 
         var gotoPage = $last[i]; }
      }
   }
```

Comment: should be the variable name. $last0, $last1, $last2...

Comment: I believe splice() requires two parameters, both being positive integers or zero.

Comment: You have one extra "}" out there, you probably forgot to comment out.

Comment: @Diodeus: I'm using it quite a lot, always like this, so I think that won't help. I think either chainging splice().toString() doesn't go or I can't declare variables like this: $last[i]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write something like:

```
if (longest.length >= 3) {
    var $last = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < longest.length-1; i++) {
      $last.push( longest[i][ longest[i].length - 1 ] );
    }
  }
```

and get the values with `$last[0]`

Or use a hash like:

```
if (longest.length >= 3) {
    var hash = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < longest.length-1; i++) {
      hash['$last'+ i] = longest[i][ longest[i].length - 1 ];
    }
  }
```

and get the content using for instance `hash.$last0`

Comment: may be give a sample of `longest`, it would help

Comment: I edited the answer, is it better? This is ok if you have just 2 levels of arrays, if you have more, it needs to recurse

Comment: `longest.length-1` is a bit strange as you will never reach the last element of longest

Comment: Your first snippet works perfectly! THANKS. I'll probably be dreaming "array-style" tonight...